# Grep R error message in bash to halt a pipeline

Tags: r, bash

I have a pipeline I am working on. I have a wrappper.sh that pipes together various .R scripts. However, This pipeline will run through an error message. I want to add a way to grep our the word Error if True, shut down pipeline. I know I need an if/else statment, but dont know how to grep this info out of .R script running in bash.sh. See an example error.

Current script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Bash script for running GeoMx Pipeline

####
# Install required R packages for pipeline
echo "installing R packages"

Rscript installPackages.R

echo "DONE! R packages installed"

#####
# Created required folders
echo "Creating Folders"

Rscript CreateFolder.R

echo "DONE! Folders created"

####
# Copy data over
cp -u -p Path/Initial\ Dataset.xlsx /PATO_TO

####
# Run Statistical Models

echo "Running Statistical Analysis"

Rscript GLM_EdgeR.R

echo "DONE! Statistical Models completed"
```

Example error:

```
Error in glmLRT(glmfit, coef = coef, contrast = contrast) :
  contrast vector of wrong length, should be equal to number of coefficients in the linear model.
Calls: glmQLFTest -> glmLRT
Execution halted
```

What I want:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Bash script for running GeoMx Pipeline

####
# Install required R packages for pipeline
echo "installing R packages"

Rscript installPackages.R

if grep error == TRUE
then 
   echo "Fatal Error, STOP Pipeline"
   STOP
else 
   echo "DONE! R packages installed"

#####
# Created required folders
echo "Creating Folders"

Rscript CreateFolder.R

if grep error == TRUE
then 
   echo "Fatal Error, STOP Pipeline"
   STOP
else 
   echo "DONE! Folders created"

####
# Copy data over
cp -u -p Path/Initial\ Dataset.xlsx /PATO_TO

####
# Run Statistical Models

echo "Running Statistical Analysis"

Rscript GLM_EdgeR.R

if grep error == TRUE
then 
   echo "Fatal Error, STOP Pipeline"
   STOP
else 
   echo "DONE! Statistical Models completed"
```

Comment: If you really **need** to parse the error message, you have to catch it. For this you have to tell us what the R-program prints to standard output and what it prints to standard error. However, if your R-script behaves sufficiently well, it will be sufficient to test its exit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to grep for errors, you can test if last status-code was non-zero:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

Rscript CreateFolder.R

exit_code=$?
if test $exit_code -ne 0
then
  echo "Fatal Error, STOP Pipeline"
  exit $exit_code
else
  echo "DONE! Folders created"
fi
```

If `Rscript CreateFolder.R` fails, bash script will exit with the same status-code.

Though if you have more of those conditions you want to check against, it makes sense to use `set -e` instead.

> Exit immediately if a pipeline, which may consist of a
> single simple command, a list, or a
> compound command returns a non-zero status.
> https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

Basically it makes your script run until something fails:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e
Rscript installPackages.R
echo "DONE! R packages installed"
Rscript CreateFolder.R
echo "DONE! Folders created"
Rscript GLM_EdgeR.R
echo "DONE! Statistical Models completed"
```

With 2nd script, `CreateFolder.R`, failing, it will look like this:

```bash
~/r# ./wrappper.sh
[1] "OK"
DONE! R packages installed
Error: object 'will_fail' not found
Execution halted
```

Comment: Why storing the exit code into a variable, if you don't want to distinguish between different non-zero exit codes? In your solution, a `if ! Rscript CreateFolder.R` would be simpler.

Comment: Simpler - yes. In that sample the  non-zero exit code will be received by `wrapper.sh` caller so it could clean up for example.  Even though in this particular case the context (actual failed call & error) will be lost.

Comment: @ margusl, Thanks for the examples! Both are perfect. The set -e solution is a nice feature, I never ran across before!